# RinohType sphinx customize the styles in PDF

Tags: python-sphinx, rinohtype

I am using [RinohType](https://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/index.html) for generating my RST files to PDF.

I am trying to understand how to provide custom styles in the PDF for my logo and other elements.

I somehow felt the explanation in the [Default matcher](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/stylesheets.html#default-matcher) doesn't provide examples on how to do this.

**conf.py**

```
rinoh_documents = [dict(doc='index',        # top-level file (index.rst)
                        target='manual',
                        template='rinohtype.rtt',
                        logo='_static/rr-logo-vertical2022-1100px-transp.png')]
```

**rhinotype.rtt**

```
[TEMPLATE_CONFIGURATION]
name = my article configuration
template = article
stylesheet = my_stylesheet.rts

parts =
    title
    ;front_matter
    contents
language = fr
abstract_location = title

[SectionTitles]
contents = 'Contents'

[AdmonitionTitles]
caution = 'Careful!'
warning = 'Please be warned'

[VARIABLES]
paper_size = A5

[title]
page_number_format = lowercase roman
end_at_page = left

[contents]
page_number_format = number

[title_page]
top_margin = 2cm
```

**my_stylesheet.rts**

Here I am trying to change the width of my logo in the PDF.
What is the correct way to give the css properties here.

```
width: 100px
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default matcher](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/stylesheets.html#default-matcher) defines the *title page logo* style. To adjust the style of this element, you can [create a style sheet that builds upon](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/basicstyling.html#extending-an-existing-style-sheet) the default *sphinx* style sheet and tweak the *title page logo* style:

```ini
[STYLESHEET]
name=My Style Sheet
description=My tweaks to the Sphinx style sheet
base=sphinx

[title page logo]
width = 4cm
```

This style accepts the [FlowableStyle](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/style/rinoh.flowable.FlowableStyle.html#rinoh.flowable.FlowableStyle) style attributes. In the linked documentation, you can see the *width* attribute supports a bunch of units but not *px*.

Please stay tuned for better documentation. Something is actually happening in that area!

P.S. If you want to make more changes to the styling of your document, the [style log](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/elementstyling.html#style-logs) can be very useful to find out which style name corresponds to a particular document element.